# Catch dismissal of BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

Is there any way to catch the dismissal/cancel of a BottomSheetDialogFragment?

**Bottom sheet class**

```
public class ContactDetailFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment
{
    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState)
        {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN)
            {
                dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset)
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setupDialog(Dialog dialog, int style)
    {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View contentView = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.fragment_contactdetail, null);

        dialog.setContentView(contentView);

        BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(((View) contentView.getParent()));
        if (mBottomSheetBehavior != null)
        {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetBehaviorCallback);
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) DisplayUtils.dpToPixels(CONTACT_DETAIL_PEEK_HEIGHT, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
        }
    }
}
```

**What I've tried that doesn't work**

- in `setupDialog` adding either of `dialog.setOnCancelListener();` or `dialog.setOnDismissListener();` never gets triggered
- the bottomsheet behavior's `onStateChanged` only gets triggered if the user drags the bottomsheet down passed the collapsed state, and there is no state for dismissed/cancelled
- adding the same oncancel/ondismiss listeners to the instantiation of the BottomSheetDialogFragment, by using `ContactDetailFragment.getDialog().setOnCancelListener()` does not get triggered

Given that it's essentially a dialog fragment, there must be some way to catch the dismissal?

Comment: Override `onDismiss` method worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found a simple solution.
Using `onDestroy` or `onDetach` in the BottomSheetDialogFragment allows me to get the dismissal correctly

Comment: Override `onCancel()` or `onDismiss()`

Comment: Go for the onCancel() that will help you to capture user cancellation by sliding down

Comment: onCancel works only when user sliding down if you want to listen all cases when dialog closed you can use onDismiss()